# SharePoint 2013 custom workflow (Sequential) visual studio not assigning task

Tags: workflow, visual-studio-2015

I am creating a simple sequential workflow using VS 2015 in SP2013 on premise. Trying to assign a task to the user in a 'Domain\username' format. The problem is that it is creating a task but not assigning it to the specified user.

createTask1_TaskProperties1.AssignedTo = "Domain"+"\"+"username";

so when an item is added workflow is in progress and when you click on it you can see the task but 'Assigned to' column is empty.

I have tested assigning it to many users (Production users, test users). its only working with one live account of my colleague. that account was site collection admin so I added other test accounts and live accounts as site collection admin. it dint work.

I created a SharePoint group and assigned by retreiving from that group but still no luck. 
I used our own AD framework to retrieve the users and assign a task, but still no luck. 
I checked the logs and I compared the account for which it is working with the other which is not working and there is not much in the logs too: I will post the logs here 
Please see the logs below for working user and non working user:
Please check and help me out as I am banging my head over this for two days.

[image]

Comment: Is the system configured for claims?

Comment: yes @Nils this was an issue. after banging my head for 2 days I compared these two accounts and it turns out 'i:w#' thing before domain was the issue and i was trimming that part in the code. But a question here. why the other account which was working did not have that string before domain name? any idea.

Comment: No. Hard to say. Maybe that account was logged in once before claims were configured? (Could be that some badly coded solution simply used `SPWeb.EnsureUser()` without the claim..)

Comment: thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completeness:

If `claims` are enabled, you need to provide the full claim, not only the "simple" login. Encoding the claim can be done via [`ConvertIdentifierToClaim`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.claims.spclaimprovidermanager.convertidentifiertoclaim?view=sharepoint-server). Whether claims are needed or not can be tested via [`UseClaimsAuthentication`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebapplication.useclaimsauthentication?view=sharepoint-server):

```
var userAccount = "domain\\user"
SPUser user;
if (web.Site.WebApplication.UseClaimsAuthentication)
{
  var claim = SPClaimProviderManager.Local.ConvertIdentifierToClaim(userAccount, SPIdentifierTypes.WindowsSamAccountName);
  user = web.EnsureUser(claim.ToEncodedString());
} else {
  user = web.EnsureUser(userAccount);
}
```

Now, the user is available in the `web` (so you're sure it can be assigned  tasks). Use `user.LoginName` as assignee.